# IIS stops download at 321 mb

Tags: git, iis, download, jetty

I'm hosting Git server with lfs behind the IIS 8.5
Lfs uses HTTP-Get to download large files. For some reason each time I try to download file from lfs storage it stops at exactly 321mb. Log says everything OK

```
017-12-21 23:59:59 192.168.x.x GET /r/repoName/info/lfs/objects/feac099b3be3d66d550028dd4eb43f342c226d4a3ca8ceba39d0df9d2b1c2995 - 80 - 192.168.y.y Mozilla/5.0+(Windows+NT+10.0;+Win64;+x64)+AppleWebKit/537.36+(KHTML,+like+Gecko)+Chrome/63.0.3239.84+Safari/537.36 - 200 0 0 10687
```

I tried to dowload via direct link from browser with same result - only 321mb. Just after that I see in WireShark that servers stops sending HTTP packets with data.

Further investigations showed me that the problem is between IIS and Jetty backend. For some reason IIS resets connection with Jetty after 300+ bytes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the problem was in `maxAllowedContentLength` parameter.
if you have such problem add this to your web.config replacing the length parameter with desired content length:

```
<security>    
  <requestFiltering>     
    <requestLimits maxAllowedContentLength="[place_length_in_bytes_here]" />
  </requestFiltering>
</security>
```